# Parse Json Object

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, json

I have an List error Entity which I used to pass errorId and error message to the UI layer.

```
   public class ErrorEntity
    {
       public int ErrorId
       {
           get;
           set;
       }

       public string ErrorMessage
       {
           get;
           set;
       }
    }
}
```

I send the object to the Javascript I am serializing it to JSON.

The Json I am getting after serialization look like

```
[{"ErrorId":1,"ErrorMessage":"Test has not been prepared for tag EP105"},{"ErrorId":2,"ErrorMessage":"Test has not been prepared for tag EP105"}]
```

Now I need to parse this Json string to show the error message to the user. Please let me know how can I parse it. Do I need to write a for loop to traverse with in it.

**EDIT** In my master page  I am trying to parse it.

```
function ShowErrorMsg(jsonObject) {  
  for (i = 0; i < jsonObject.Object.length; i++) { //Object is undefined here.
    alert(jsonObject.Object.ErrorMessage);
  }          
}
```

Comment: are you using any ajax based libraries like jquery? Some browsers have native ability to parse json string. Which is(are) your target browser(s)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prefer [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) if it's available:

```
var jsonArray = JSON.parse(serializedString);
window.alert(jsonArray[0].ErrorMessage);
```

Fall back to [eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) otherwise:

```
var jsonArray = eval(serializedString);
window.alert(jsonArray[0].ErrorMessage);
```

Comment: What is the more preferred way of doing it. Would eval be safe?

Comment: The preferred way to do it is to use `JSON.parse()`, which only parses the subset of Javascript used by JSON and is safer than `eval()`.

Comment: You should use a library like jQuery which should implement the fallback if your browser does not support JSON.parse().

Answer (score 0):

Try [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/)

Comment: I am trying to parse it in my script file.

Answer (score 0):

There is support in most browsers for parsing json, I recommend to use [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) for this - you also can take a look at [this](http://www.json.org/js.html)

Be aware - Its better to use a library - and not using JS for this (JS is from the devil ;) )